# how can i create a preview for multiple upload buttons

Tags: javascript, php

How can i preview the selected ico with multiple inputs? The problem is that it select  the input by id which is everywhere the same. How can i run the js with a indefined amount of inputs? The amount of inputs depends on the number of loops it ran. What can i do to make it work with multiple inputs

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $number; $x++) {
    $bar .= '<input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Name '.$x.'" id="title" value=""><input type="file" accept="video/*" name="file[]"/><input type="file" name="" class="icofile" id="icofile"  accept="image/*" name="icon[]" hidden>
  <label for="icofile" class="icofile" id="selector"><img src="../images/none.png"></label><br>';
  }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var loader = function(e){
  let file = e.target.files;

  //let show= "<span>Selected file : </span>"+file[0].name;
  let show= "<img src='none.png'>";

  let output= document.getElementById("selector");
  output.innerHTML = show;
  output.classList.add("active");
  if(file[0].type.match("image")){
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function(e){
      let data=e.target.result;
      let image= document.createElement("img");
      image.src=data;

      output.innerHTML="";
      output.insertBefore(image,null);
      output.classList.add("image");
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
  }else{
    let show="<img src='none.png'>";
    //show= show+file[0].name;

    output.innerHTML=show;
    output.classList.add("active");

    if(output.classList.contains("image")){
      output.classList.remove("image");   
    }
  }
};
let fileInput = document.getElementById("icofile");
fileInput.addEventListener("change", loader);
</script>
```

Comment: Cant you use `onchange=newFunction(this)` inside input and create `function newFunction(val){}` to do the job? Should be easier

Answer (score 0):

You got quite some redundant (repetitive) code that you could remove. Using [Object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) could make it easier for you if you ditch the unnecessary FileReader that waste time encoding decoding long base64 urls.

also you don't have uniq id's throughout your html. and you used `name` twice on the icofile input... so this problems have to be fixed first before you move on.
also the label with the `for="icofile"` will only point to the first input so it also needs to be uniq.

```js
globalThis.preview = function preview (evt) {
  const file = evt.target.files[0]
  // Get matching label
  const output = document.querySelector(`label[for=${evt.target.id}]`)
  // Reuse the existing image instead of clearing and rebuilding
  const img = output.querySelector('img')
  
  output.classList.add('active')
  output.classList.remove('image')

  // This if statement is almost useless since
  // accept="image/*" ensure that you only get images
  if (file.type.match('image')) {
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    output.classList.add('image')
  } else {
    img.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ff0000/000000&text=None'
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- for loop that did output this: -->
<!-- foreach id in this list append an index -->

<input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Name" id="title-1">
<input type="file" name="file[]" accept="video/*"  />
<input type="file" name="icon[]" accept="image/*" onchange="preview(event)" id="icofile-1" hidden>
<label for="icofile-1" class="icofile">
  <img width="50" height="50" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ff0000/000000&text=None">
</label>

<hr> <!-- for better look/seperation without css. -->

<input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Name" id="title-2">
<input type="file" name="file[]" accept="video/*"  />
<input type="file" name="icon[]" accept="image/*" onchange="preview(event)" id="icofile-2" hidden>
<label for="icofile-2" class="icofile">
  <img width="50" height="50" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ff0000/000000&text=None">
</label>
```